# iPhone serial port programming

Tags: ios, xcode, serial-port, arduino

I have a [jailbroken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking) iPhone running iOS 5.1.1. I am using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 4.3.2, and I am developing an app that will hopefully talk to a [Parallax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax,_Inc._%28company%29) [RFID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) reader. Essentially I want users of the app to be able to login using an RFID card as opposed to inputting their username and pin, but I still have a lot of work to do to get this done.

The app I am developing is being loaded onto the phone via [Cydia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydia), so accessing the serial port `/dev/tty.iap` on the phone shouldn't be a problem.

I created two files `Seiral.h` and `Serial.c` for opening the serial port.

The code for `Serial.c` is similar to what is found in the [devdot tutorial](http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial), and I think I am sucessfully opening the serial port because I am getting this message in the console:

> Aug 18 19:33:34 3GS KegCop[520]: The serial data is 16

How would I read the RFID badge number being scanned on the Parallax reader?

I am using an Arduino to talk between the iPhone and the RFID reader. When the RFID badge is scanned, it sends the badge number out via the serial out on the Arduino, but I am not sure how I would read the data on the iPhone side of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently still working on this solution, but I did manage to find a good serial console app with a [tutorial](http://inornate.springnote.com/pages/8139470?print=1), that will work as a starting point for a foundation for getting the serial communication working within the app I am currently developing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the datasheet of the parallax to understand the serial data format.  This page explains how to do it with arduino, and has link to the datasheet.  http://makeprojects.com/Project/Using-the-Parallax-RFID-Reader-with-an-Arduino/617/1#.UDJyyd2GqSp

On iphone it would be no different.  Just read the serial port and parse the data according to the datasheet.

What are you using arduino for?  Just voltage level translation?  That would work, but you can also get simpler/cheaper/smaller converters for RS232 to TTL.

Comment: I already have a sketch loaded on the Arduino that reads the RFID card # and then sends it out via the serial port on the Arduino.  I am struggling with the Obj-c Xcode interfacing of the serial port to the Arduino.